# media9 and Acrobat

Tags: media9, acrobat

I often have a problem with video playback integrated in Acrobat by MEDIA9. The file can be read on some items and not others.
so I ask these questions

- What is the minimum version of Acrobat Reader to view the videos embedded by MEDIA9 (mp4) under windows
- Should we install plugins to view videos?
- Should you install any codecs?

PS: the last document with which I have problems is available here:
http://sciences-indus-cpge.papanicola.info/Utilisation-de-Scilab-Xcos-pour
thank you

Comment: The three videos in the PDF downloaded from the link you provided run perfectly here. I am using Adobe Reader 10.1.8 for Windows (with bundled Flash Player). Newer Readers need the Flash Player (for-Firefox-version) installed separately.

Comment: thank you, but it does not directly answer my question.
What is the minimum configuration?

Comment: Adobe Reader 9+, FlashPlayer plugin for Firefox in case of A-Reader 10+, video in MP4+H.264 or FLV formats.